# Ошибка при сборке проекта с помощью maven

Tags: maven, alfresco

Это модель контента для alfresco. Проект скачан с GitBucket.

Ошибка

[image]

Файл pom.xml в папке repo

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.admnkz.docnkz</groupId>
  <artifactId>appeal-main</artifactId>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
 </parent>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <artifactId>appeal-repo</artifactId>
 <name>appeal-repo</name>
 <description>appeal-repo</description>

 <profiles>
  <profile>
   <id>dev</id>
   <activation>
    <property>
     <name>profile</name>
     <value>dev</value>
    </property>
   </activation>
   <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
       <execution>
        <id>2</id>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <configuration>
         <tasks>
          <delete>
           <fileset dir="${alfresco.server.path}/modules/platform/"
            includes="**/${project.artifactId}.*" />
          </delete>
          <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.jar"
           todir="${alfresco.server.path}/modules/platform/" />
         </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
         <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
       </execution>
      </executions>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
  </profile>
 </profiles>

 <build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-surefire-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.2</version>
    <configuration>
     <skipTests>true</skipTests>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <id>1</id>
      <phase>prepare-package</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>run</goal>
      </goals>
      <configuration>
       <target>
        <!-- BPMN files -->
        <copy todir="${project.build.directory}/classes">
         <fileset dir="src/main/resources" />
         <mapper type="glob" from="*.bpmn" to="*.bpmn20.xml" />
        </copy>
        <delete>
         <fileset dir="${project.build.directory}/classes"
          includes="**/*.bpmn" />
        </delete>
       </target>

      </configuration>
     </execution>
    </executions>
   </plugin>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <files>
      <file>../${profile}.properties</file>
     </files>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>junit</groupId>
   <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.anarchy.alfresco</groupId>
   <artifactId>alfresco-repo-util</artifactId>
   <version>${assocm1.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.anarchy.alfresco</groupId>
   <artifactId>assocm1-repo</artifactId>
   <version>${assocm1.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.anarchy.alfresco</groupId>
   <artifactId>hidename-repo</artifactId>
   <version>${hidename.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.anarchy.alfresco</groupId>
   <artifactId>organ-repo</artifactId>
   <version>${organ.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>  
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.anarchy.alfresco</groupId>
   <artifactId>multicontent-repo</artifactId>
   <version>${multicontent.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>net.anarchy.alfresco</groupId>
   <artifactId>advancedwf-repo</artifactId>
   <version>${advancedwf.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>org.admnkz.docnkz</groupId>
   <artifactId>docnkz-repo</artifactId>
   <version>${docnkz.version}</version>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>  
  
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

Файл pom.xml в папке share

```html
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
 xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
 <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
 <parent>
  <groupId>org.admnkz.docnkz</groupId>
  <artifactId>appeal-main</artifactId>
  <version>1.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <relativePath>../pom.xml</relativePath>
 </parent>
 <packaging>jar</packaging>
 <artifactId>appeal-share</artifactId>
 <name>appeal-share</name>
 <description>appeal-share</description>
 <profiles>
  <profile>
   <id>dev</id>
   <activation>
    <property>
     <name>profile</name>
     <value>dev</value>
    </property>
   </activation>
   <build>
    <plugins>
     <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
      <executions>
       <execution>
        <phase>install</phase>
        <configuration>
         <tasks>
          <delete>
           <fileset dir="${alfresco.server.path}/modules/share/"
            includes="**/${project.artifactId}.*" />
          </delete>
          <copy file="${project.build.directory}/${project.artifactId}.jar"
           todir="${alfresco.server.path}/modules/share/" />
         </tasks>
        </configuration>
        <goals>
         <goal>run</goal>
        </goals>
       </execution>
      </executions>
     </plugin>
    </plugins>
   </build>
  </profile>
 </profiles>
 <build>
  <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
  <plugins>
   <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>properties-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-alpha-2</version>
    <executions>
     <execution>
      <phase>initialize</phase>
      <goals>
       <goal>read-project-properties</goal>
      </goals>
     </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
     <files>
      <file>../${profile}.properties</file>
     </files>
    </configuration>
   </plugin>
  </plugins>
 </build>
 <dependencies>
  <dependency>
   <groupId>${alfresco.groupId}</groupId>
   <artifactId>share</artifactId>
   <classifier>classes</classifier>
   <scope>provided</scope>
  </dependency>
 </dependencies>
</project>
```

В чем может быть дело?

Answer (score 0):

1) В родительском pom.xml не указано свойство dependency.surf.version

```
Например
<dependency.surf.version>6.10</dependency.surf.version>
```

2) Зависимости, не доступны в публичном nexus, ищете настройки для этого проекта

```
<groupId>net.anarchy.alfresco</groupId>
<artifactId>advancedwf-repo</artifactId>
<version>${advancedwf.version}</version>

<groupId>net.anarchy.alfresco</groupId>
<artifactId>hidename-repo</artifactId>
<version>${hidename.version}</version>
```